# Geometry calculation in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, geometry, azimuth

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

I have many point (i.e. off-scale) bridges for which it is necessary to calculate the strike azimuth of the symbol.

How can I do this?

I know about the "line bearing" tool but it works for line features.

Comment: Calculating azimuth requires two points, but is otherwise really easy. Please [Edit] the Question to indicate what you have tried, and where you are stuck.